# How can I create a polycarbonate roof valley?

Tags: roof, joints

[image]

My roof valley is wider than this. I want light to pass in through. Is the polycarbonate I should use? Can I make a joint somewhere in the middle through the length with polycarbonate.  I need some advice to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a difficult time getting approval for a non-traditional material in a roof assembly, code wise.

Additionally, polycarbonate has degradation problems with UV light: [City Plastics](http://www.cityplastics.com.au/uv_resistance.html)

Acrylic or safety glass might be a better choice.

HOWEVER, the real fly-in-the-ointment is the structure necessary UNDER the roof valley, which is not transparent.

Stick with standard roof windows BETWEEN the framing members.  It will be warrantied, accepted by your insurance and code authority, and easily installable by a journeyman roofer.